# Running function on WooCommerce refund causes 500 error

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook, custom-fields

I'm running into an issue with the following function.

What I'm trying to do is update a custom field when refunding a customer in WooCommerce, but it causes a 500 server error notice in my javascript console on applying the refund, also the desired change doesn't take affect as the custom field doesn't get updated.

Maybe I'm using the wrong action hooks?

```
// Adjust custom field after refund

function adjust_tpv_after_refund( $order_id, $refund_id ) {
    $user_id = $order_id->get_user_id();
    $progress = get_the_author_meta( 'tier_progress_value', $user_id );
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $refund_amount = $order->get_total_refunded();
    $adjusted_field = $progress - $refund_amount; 
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'tier_progress_value', $adjusted_field );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_fully_refunded', 'adjust_tpv_after_refund', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_partially_refunded', 'adjust_tpv_after_refund', 10, 2 );
```

**The console error:**

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?_fs_blog_admin=true:1

After clicking refund the ajax spinner spins endlessly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling get_user_id() on $order_id, You need to reorder the first three lines and replace `$order_id->get_user_id()` with `$order->get_user_id()`

```
$order    = wc_get_order( $order_id );
$user_id  = $order->get_user_id();
$progress = get_the_author_meta( 'tier_progress_value', $user_id );
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks for the help!